# How to create vmlinuz and initrd

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, alpine-linux

I need to create vmlinuz and initrd that will allow to launch linux with some custom scripts and settings.

How to do it properly?

I've found https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/How_to_make_a_custom_ISO_image that describes how to create ISO image but as I understand ISO and vmlinuz are different things.

Comment: Yes. ISO image is complete package which contains the vmlinuz,initrd and filesystem. while vmlinuz is the only kernel image (part of the ISO image). So in your case can you provide more details like which arch and platform are you using.

Comment: @vinodmaverick I use 64 arch. What I need is to package vmlinuz + initrd in a way that alpine linux will be launched with some packages and scripts from me. Maybe I should create such ISO and take vmlinuz and initrd from it?

Comment: initrd an vmlinuz generally resides in your /boot directory. So once you will installed the new OS on the target. you can see your initrd and vmlinuz on the same place. Later you can modify your initrd and vmlinuz according to your requirements. 

https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/DIY_Fully_working_Alpine_Linux_for_Allwinner_and_Other_ARM_SOCs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had moby `initrd` and `vmlinuz`.

1. `vmlinuz` is a kernel to load. No need to modify it for vm
2. `initrd` is what I needed.

I had to unpack it:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp
gunzip -c initrd.img | cpio -i
```

So we will have access to the filesystem that will be loaded after the kernel. I made my changes and packed it back to `initrd.img` with a command

```
find . | cpio -o -H newc | gzip > ../new-initrd.img
```